# Trying to learn while loops getting unexpected indent and syntax errors? (python)

Tags: python

The following code gives me unexpected indent I have tried many variations but I keep getting these errors or syntax errors

```
while True:
try:
    a=int(input("Please enter a number to be counted down to: "))
    b=(a-1)
    for count in range (100,b,-1):
        print (count)
        break
except:
print ("wohoo")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while loop needs a contained code block:

```
while True:    
    try:
        a = int(input("Please enter a number to be counted down to: "))
        b = (a-1)

        for count in range(100, b, -1):
            print(count)

    except:
        print ("wohoo")
```

Comment: The code now doesn't function. when ran after accepting the user input it just spams "100"

Comment: That's because of the break **you** added. Remove it to remove the effect.

Comment: Does it work now Crimson? Break exits the loop altogether, so only 100 will be printed.